# toolbar icons won't update automatically

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm developing an Eclipse product. I have defined two different perspective, edit and debug. In the toolbar of the debug perspective i placed  a set of buttons to guide the debug process flow(e.g. step over, step into, etc..). I used the eclipse command to implement the logic. Below the fragment of pluxin.xml where i declare the toolbar command.

```
     <toolbar
           id=".."
           label="Debug navigation command">
        ....
        <command
              commandId="org.eclipse.debug.ui.commands.Terminate"
              disabledIcon="icons/16x16/stop_disabled.ico"
              icon="icons/16x16/stop.ico"
              label="Terminate"
              style="push"
              tooltip="Terminate">
           <visibleWhen
                 checkEnabled="false">
              <with
                    variable="activeWorkbenchWindow.activePerspective">
                 <equals
                       value="org.xvr.xvrengine.perspective.debug">
                 </equals>
              </with>
           </visibleWhen>
        </command>
     </toolbar>
```

The problem is that while all the other icons associated to the command org.eclipse.debug.ui.commands.Terminate are updated by eclipse(active only when the process is selected in the debug view), the command i define is not updated. The editor updates the command icon if i change perspective and then switch back to the debug perspective.

How can i update the command icon? is possible to use the default eclipse icon? if i leave the "icon" entry empty the toolbar is filled with the command label.

thanks

Comment: You say the icon is updated?  Do you mean enabled/disabled state (which would have nothing to do with the XML you've posted)?

Comment: the toolbar command i defined is not updated(enabled/disabled)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but it is not clear for me what you want to achieve. If you would like to create a debugger, I suggest reusing the existing framework for that, see http://eclipse.org/articles/Article-Debugger/how-to.html and http://eclipse.org/articles/Article-Launch-Framework/launch.html

In this case you get automatically the debug frameworks icons, that are updated correspondingly.

Otherwise you might consult http://blog.eclipse-tips.com/2009/02/commands-part-5-authentication-in-rcp.html for ideas of dynamic command handling.

**Update:** Alternative answer:
You could use `fireEvent(new DebugEvent(this, DebugEvent.RESUME, detail));` as described in the end of the following Eclipse Corner article: http://eclipse.org/articles/Article-Debugger/how-to.html

This is described in the part Debug Events. I believe, that is close to what you need.

Comment: I'm actually using the existing debug framework. This adds contributions to the run menu and allows to navigate the debug process flow also in the debug view. But i would like to add the same commands available on the right top corner of the debug view or in the run menu also on the main toolbar. The commands i added work correctly but their state(enable/disable) is not updated automatically. The suggested article is very interesting but i can not figured out how can i make something similar.

Comment: If you create your own menu contribution, its enabled state has also to be defined using core expressions (enabledWhen under the contribution in the XML tree). If you already tried that option, then I have sadly no further idea.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately i think that i cannot use "enableWhen" because I didn't define the command, I use the one defined by the debug framework which i think should have already an enableWhen field.

Comment: I updated the answer to include an alternative approach by using the fireEvent function in the debugger, by you state that the debugger state has changed.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 places where you can control the enabled state of your command.

1. in org.eclipse.ui.handlers, you can
   associate your handler with your
   command and provide an enabledWhen
   core expression.  See
   http://wiki.eclipse.org/Command_Core_Expressions
   and
   http://wiki.eclipse.org/Platform_Expression_Framework
2. While your handler is active, its
   enabled state reflects in the
   command.  Most handlers subclass
   org.eclipse.core.commands.AbstractHandler.
   As your handler updates its state
   using
   `org.eclipse.core.commands.AbstractHandler.setBaseEnabled(boolean)`
   that enabled state will be reflected
   in the UI

.

Comment: Right, but the problem is that i'm not defining a new command. I'm using the one provided by the debug framework:"org.eclipse.debug.ui.commands.Terminate". Can i associate an handler to it?

Comment: Where are the other icons (that are updated correctly) coming from?  How are they contributed?

Comment: both in the run menu and on the debug view, in the top right corner of the view. I think they should come from org.eclipse.debug.ui